# 10+u(t) as a voltage to find i0(t)

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image]

I was asked to determine the value current i0(t) in the circuit, but I am not clear about u(t). Can someone explain it to me?

I found out that the 5 + 10u(t) is telling us that when t = 0, Vinput is 5 V, when t= infinity, Vinput is 10 V. Is it correct if I find the Req and make an equation about Vc

Vc= Vc(0) + ( Vc(0) - Vc(infinity) ) > e^(-t/RC))

and then calculate the i(o) and i(infinity) through KVL and KCL by using Vc(0) and Vc(infinity), and finally make an equation of

i0(t) = i0(0) + (i0(0) - i0(infinity)) > e^(-t/RC))

Is it possible?

Comment: `u(t)` is likely the unit step function. The voltage is 5V for `t<0`. The voltage is 15V for `t>=0`. Can you solve the problem if the voltage was simply 5V? How would you have proceeded? Please write down the corresponding KCL or KVL equations if that was how you planned to solve the problem.

Comment: Calculate charge store(voltage ) in capacitor at (t=0 -) assuming voltage source of 5v connected to circuit for a long time and after t=0 a voltage source of 15v is applied then calculate currents taking initial condition (t=0-) of capacitor into consideration .

Comment: may i know about what is the meaning of 5+10u(t)?

Comment: @brian it means that V = 5 at t = 0, and V = 5 + 10 for t > 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we have the following function:

$$5+10\cdot\theta\left(t\right)=
\begin{cases}
5 & \text{if}\space t<0\space\wedge\space t\to0^-\\
\\
15 & \text{if}\space t>0\space\wedge\space t\to0^+
\end{cases}
\tag1$$

So, in your circuit we need to solve for \$\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)\$ when the input voltage is equal to \$5\space\text{V}\$.

---

First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica) to solve this problem. When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2NcK6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\tag2$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

We also know that \$-\text{n}\cdot\text{I}_2=\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1\$.

Substitute \$(3)\$ into \$(2)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}=\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}+\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_4}\\
\\
-\text{n}\cdot\frac{\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}=\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

Now, we can solve for the transfer function:

$$\mathcal{H}:=\frac{\text{I}_3}{\text{V}_\text{i}}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)+\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\text{R}_4\right)}\tag5$$

Where I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 == I2 + I3, I1 == (Vi - V1)/R1, I2 == V2/R2, 
   I3 == (V2 - V3)/R3, I3 == V3/R4, -n*I2 == V2 - V1}, {I1, I2, I3, 
   V1, V2, V3}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> ((R2 + R3 + R4) Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I2 -> ((R3 + R4) Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  I3 -> (R2 Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V1 -> ((n + R2) (R3 + R4) Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + 
    R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V2 -> (R2 (R3 + R4) Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4)), 
  V3 -> (R2 R4 Vi)/((n + R2) (R3 + R4) + R1 (R2 + R3 + R4))}}
```

When we want to apply the derivation from above to your circuit we need to use [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (I will use lower case function names for the functions that are in the (complex) s-domain, so \$\text{y}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is the Laplace transform of the function \$\text{Y}\left(t\right)\$):

- $$\text{R}_4=\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\tag6$$
- The input voltage, \$\text{V}_\text{i}\$, is a stable DC voltage equal to \$\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\$, so:
  $$\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\tag7$$

So, the transfer function can be rewritten as follows:

$$\mathscr{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{v}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)}{\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}}=\frac{\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)+\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{R}_3+\frac{1}{\text{sC}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\text{sC}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{sC}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{sC}\text{R}_3+1\right)}\tag8$$

So, the output current is given by:

$$\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}}{\text{s}}\cdot\frac{\text{sC}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{sC}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{sC}\text{R}_3+1\right)}=$$
$$\frac{\hat{\text{u}}_\text{i}\text{CR}_2}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{sC}\left(\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3\right)\right)+\left(\text{n}+\text{R}_2\right)\left(\text{sC}\text{R}_3+1\right)}\tag9$$

Now, we can apply the [final value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem) to find that:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{I}_3\left(t\right)=\lim_{\text{s}\to0}\text{s}\cdot\text{i}_3\left(\text{s}\right)=0\space\text{A}\tag{10}$$

Comment: I'd upvote but the OP does not want the full solution. By the way, in equation (1), shouldn't it be 15 for `t>0` according to the unit step function's definiton? I didn't check the full solution so I'm not sure if it changes the result.

Comment: My lect didnt teach us Laplace transformation, all my lect said was, this is a 1st order circuit question only, and i was completely blank at it.